# Can I create a new Gnome terminal tab without leaving a symlink to a directory?

Tags: gnome-terminal

When I am in Gnome terminal, I create a new Gnome terminal tab by Ctrl+Shift+t.

If I am under a symlink `dir1`to a directory `dir2` in a gnome terminal tab, then I will be under the linked directory `dir2` rather than under `dir1`, after the above creation of a new tab.

I wonder how to create a new tab, so that I could still be under the symlink, rather the linked directory?

Comment: a hard link cannot link to a directory

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using an old version of gnome-terminal (3.6 or older). In 3.8 the technical solution for figuring out the working directory was changed to a completely different method, which – among other benefits – fixed this issue.